# Anyone facing Xcode crash with building with Xcode 12?

Tags: ios, swift5, arm64, xcode12, xcode-build-settings

Our app was building fine till Xcode 12 beta 2. But since beta 3 all the Xcode version just crashes whenever I try to build the project. Not able to build for simulator as well as devices. I saw similar issue discussed on swift forum where, recommended setting is to remove valid_arch. I tried that solution, but it doesn't work for me.

Spent more than 2 weeks behind this. It will great help if anyone can help here.

Comment: Someone posted this question in apple forum as well https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/661230

Comment: Xcode 12.1 beta was able to solve the issue for me.